# ORA-04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock object - Oracle Package

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, exadata

I have an Oracle Package (Schema1) that is calling another Oracle Package (Schema2) over a DB link. There are no recent code changes.

When I try to compile the package in (Schema1) it throws the following errors.

(replaced the actual schema names with 1 and 2 for clarity)

> ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object
>   SCHEMA2.PKG_NAMEHERE@SCHEMA2.LINKNAME.INT@SCHEMA1
>
> ORA-04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock object
>   SCHEMA2.PKG_NAMEHERE@SCHEMA2.LINKNAME.INT@SCHEMA1

What we have tried

1. Killed all user sessions
2. Recompiled the package in SCHEMA2 even so SCHEMA1 that calls it over the DBLINK failes with "ORA-04020: deadlock detected"

We have 4 Database regions, and this is only happening in two of the regions.

**Notes:**

```
SCHEMA1: Oracle 11g

SCHEMA2: Oracle 12c (on ExaData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this webpage https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/nameresolution.htm#LNPLS017, especially the INNER CAPTURE section. 
Does the package exist on both sides of the link or only one? 
What does the ORA-60 deadlock trace file show?
What does DBMS_UTILITY.NAME_RESOLVE show for "SCHEMA2.PKG_NAMEHERE@SCHEMA2.LINKNAME.INT@SCHEMA1"?
Do the DBLINKS loopback?

Comment: The package exists, this is an existing package (both sides) been working for years, then this just happened.